# How can I calculate row count totals (count(*)) for each week day (Monday, Tuesday, etc.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know how can I calculate total row counts stratified by day of the week

```
SELECT 
    OPERATOR,
   [Monday],
   [Tuesday] ,
   [Wednesday] ,
   [Thursday] ,
   [Friday] 
   COUNT(*) AS TOTAL -- i can not do this / HOW TO MAKE ?
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
           OPERATOR, 
           Datename(weekday, TAB_DATE) DAY
    FROM   #TABLES
    WHERE 
    TAB_DATE>=DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) 
    AND TAB_DATE<DATEADD(wk,1,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)) and
    OPERATOR_ID IN (111,222,444)  GROUP BY ID,OPERATOR,TAB_DATE
    ) AS  p  
    PIVOT ( 
    COUNT (ID) 
    FOR DAY IN ( [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday]))  pvt
```

Comment: Is good that you post the invalid SQL that would represent what you want to achieve but is even better if you post an example of the content of the input table and what the output for that toy input example should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all you have in subquery and then add each day result to make a total:

```
SELECT
  *,
  [Monday] + [Tuesday] + [Wednesday] + [Thursday] + [Friday] AS TOTAL
FROM (
  SELECT 
     OPERATOR,
     [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday] 
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
      ID, OPERATOR, Datename(weekday, TAB_DATE) DAY
    FROM #TABLES
    WHERE TAB_DATE>=DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) 
      AND TAB_DATE<DATEADD(wk,1,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0))
      AND OPERATOR_ID IN (111,222,444)
    GROUP BY ID, OPERATOR, TAB_DATE
    ) AS  p  
    PIVOT ( 
    COUNT (ID) 
    FOR DAY IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday])
    ) pvt 
  ) t
```

I have formatted your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use OVER Clause for this:

```
SELECT 
    OPERATOR,
   [Monday],
   [Tuesday] ,
   [Wednesday] ,
   [Thursday] ,
   [Friday],
   COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ID, 
           OPERATOR, 
           Datename(weekday, TAB_DATE) DAY
    FROM   #TABLES
    WHERE 
    TAB_DATE>=DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0) 
    AND TAB_DATE<DATEADD(wk,1,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)) and
    OPERATOR_ID IN (111,222,444)  GROUP BY ID,OPERATOR,TAB_DATE
    ) AS  p  
    PIVOT ( 
    COUNT (ID) 
    FOR DAY IN ( [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday]))  pvt
```